# Access to system imagelist

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am creating a treeview which wil have folder images for directories and want to know if there is a way to access the system image list so that I can display the system default folder image.

Thx
Mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box image list for the system images (they depend on things like the current visual theme). The entry for [`SHGetFileInfo` at pinvoke.net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32/SHGetFileInfo.html) has a code sample for extracting icons for files (and, I presume, folders). You can use that and dynamically populate an `ImageList` component to get the tree view display the appropriate icons.

Answer (score 2):

To get the current system icons you should take a look into the registry at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\DefaultIcon`. Here you'll find the path and position of the used folder icon.